# Are DELETE/PUT http verbs needed?

Tags: rest, http

I don't see a huge benefit of designing a REST API service that uses PUT and DELETE to update and delete data. These 2 verbs can be easily replaced by using a POST and a unique url.

The only benefit I see of using PUT and DELETE is it cuts down the number of url's that the REST API service uses which isn't much. Are there other benefits that I'm overlooking?

Comment: As you switch from the REST patterns to tunneling everything through a single endpoint through POSTs, you are switching from a well known protocol that infrastructure assumes is being used completely to an ad hoc protocol that infrastructure can't use.  Move towards tunneling an ad hoc protocol through POST when HTTP and REST are just such poor fits for your underlying API that you feel you have no choice.

Answer (score 6):

This actually has not so much to do with REST, but more with the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP).

The basic idea of HTTP is that you perform a certain action (one of the HTTP methods, such as GET, POST, PUT and DELETE) on a certain resource (identified by its URL). So if you start deviating from that by adding the action into the URL (such as http://example.com/api/books/123/delete) and using a different HTTP method, you are violating the HTTP protocol.

The downsides of this might not be instantly visible (because it will still work), and might be limited if you are only using the API by yourself. However, if other programmers are using the API as well, you are creating certain expectations by stating that you have a RESTful HTTP API while you are actually not adhering to the protocol.

For instance, if calling `GET /api/books/123` returns a representation of the book resource, a developer expects to be able to call `PUT` on that same URL to update the information on that book, and `DELETE` to remove the book alltogether. (of course, if he does not have permissions to do that, you don't actually remove the book but you return a 403 'Forbidden' or 405 'Method Not Allowed' status code - which are also part of the HTTP specification)

However, if you deviate from the protocol (basically inventing your own protocol), you will have to describe somewhere that instead of calling `DELETE /api/books/123` developers have to call `POST /api/books/123/remove/the/book`. They will have to be aware of all your API's custom rules because you are not following the standard.

Another good point is made by Darrel Miller in his answer. The HTTP methods all have a certain meaning and also certain characteristics. For instance, `GET` is supposed to be a *safe method*, used to retrieve information without making any changes on the server side. And `PUT` and `DELETE` are *idempotent*, which means that (even though they are not *safe* methods like `GET`) you can make as many requests as you like without any unwanted side effects (deleting a book one or ten times has the same effect: the book is gone). `POST` however is not idempotent: if you do ten `POST` requests to create a new book, you will most likely end up with 10 duplicate book entries.

Because of these characteristics, developers and tools are able to make certain assumptions. For instance, a search indexer such as Googlebot will only do `GET` requests, in order to not break anything on the server. However, if you would be violating the HTTP specification by having a URL `http://example.com/api/books/123/delete` in order to delete a book, you might notice at one day that your database is completely empty because Google has been indexing your site. That wouldn't be Google's fault but yours, because you didn't follow the specification.

So to make a long story short: using a protocol or standard (such as HTTP) sets certain expectations, and if you then deviate from the protocol you will create unexpected behavior and possible unwanted side effects.

Comment: So "HTTP is just a certain action on a certain resource identified by its URL"? That rather sounds like a very narrow overview that leaves behind a lot of cases. I think this is not "basic idea of HTTP". This is basic idea of REST. Basic idea of HTTP is requests and responses. Resources and actions are abstractions to be implemented.

Answer (score 4):

It is not required to use PUT and DELETE to get the benefits of a REST based system.

Using the more precise methods can be advantageous in certain cases.  Usually it is intermediary components that take advantage of the semantics.  PUT and DELETE are idempotent methods, so if some generic component receives a 503, in theory it could retry a PUT/DELETE until it gets a successful response.  With a POST method, the intermediary can't do that.

With a DELETE method a client knows not to send a body.  With a PUT, it knows to send a complete representation.  With a POST method, you need to communicate to the client how to make the request in some other way, like a link relation.

Answer (score 0):

You can live without PUT and DELETE.

This article tells you why: http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/why_put_and_delete.html

..BUT (quote from Fielding): "A REST API should not contain any changes to the communication protocols aside from filling-out or fixing the details of underspecified bits of standard protocols, such as HTTP’s PATCH method or Link header field. Workarounds for broken implementations (such as those browsers stupid enough to believe that HTML defines HTTP’s method set) should be defined separately, or at least in appendices, with an expectation that the workaround will eventually be obsolete. [Failure here implies that the resource interfaces are object-specific, not generic.] "
(http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven)